# Syntax for compiling c++ code with preprocessor option in Intel Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, preprocessor

I am trying to compile a c++ script using Intel Compiler 17.0 Update 4 Intel(R) Visual Studio 2013. What is the correct compiler syntax if I want to invoke the preprocessor option?

The same script was successfully compiled in Linux using the following syntax:

```
    sudo g++ script.cpp -o script -DUNIX -cpp
```

Looking at the preprocessor options summary here -->
[https://www.lri.fr/~lacas/Teaching/SIMD/icc.pdf](https://www.lri.fr/%7Elacas/Teaching/SIMD/icc.pdf)

it looks like I can either preprocess to an .i file or ::stdout.

However I want to invoke the preprocessor in the command line compile statement such that it will generate an executable. I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
    cl script.cpp /EHsc /MT /optionX
```

where optionX is the equivalent of "-cpp" for the Intel VS compiler.

Is there such an option?

I tried the `/fpp` option which throws this warning:

```
   cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/fpp'
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: `cl` is the Microsoft C++ compiler frontend program. And Visual Studio is also a Microsoft IDE (Integrated Development Environment).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/p-preprocess-to-a-file?view=vs-2019

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should *never* need to build general programs as the super-user, in any operating system. So that`sudo` shouldn't be needed. Also C++ programs are not "scripts". Please take some time to do some research about the programs you're actually using, and the correct terms used, as you seem to have many misunderstandings.